# Electronic components pressure rating

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, batteries, resistors, electrolytic-capacitor

I have made a custom PCB that measures acceleration. The PCB contains components such as op-amps, SMD resistors, COG capacitors, and tantalum capacitors. The circuit is powered by a saft ls14500 AA battery. I wanted to if any of these components have a pressure rating including the battery. I was planning to use this circuit under a vacuum. Just wanted to know if the circuit would work in a vacuum.

Comment: A regular AA battery won't work in vacuum at the very least.

Comment: Only the Saft Tech Support can advise you on the perform for abnormal high stress environments even if Laser  welded Lithium with a mechanical vent.  It might only vent in one direction. https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1781034.pdf

Comment: What about tantalum capacitors because they are a subtype of electrolytic capacitors. I am worried they might damage the board.

Comment: All the parts need to be verified if Aerospace Qualified with supplier , datasheets and part numbers. along with system design thermal response in a vaccum

Comment: In Aerospace back in the '70's, I used Tantalum axial Kemet parts and large silver oxide batteries, but you have to do your own due diligence. We aren't clairvoyant to your design.

Comment: http://everyspec.com/NASA/NASA-General/

Comment: The battery and any electrolytic capacitors will be your (first) culprits.

Comment: Example qualified MIL-PRF-55365/4   https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_T2001_T409.pdf and this https://www.doeeet.com/content/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/MIL-STD-1580.pdf

Comment: Most avionics uses COTS devices usually industrial temperature rated including stuff that will be in an unpressurised bay. Those would be fine although I stopped using tantalums of any description some time ago. I have no idea about the battery.

Comment: Under high power ripple stress the hard MnO2 had combustion issues with thermal expansion and shrinking dielectric gap, Yet reliable with lower stress factors. The polymer soft coated tantalum films (above link) don't have those thermal issues and have 20x lower ESR with a broader spectral range. Consult your FAE when in doubt.